# converting from mysql_results to mysqli_results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to convert my scripts over from MYSQL_ to mySQLI_
I just want to switch over via procedural for now then I'll move to oops

I used to do this -- WITH mysql_

```
db_connect(_DBHOSTNAME_,_DBUSERNAME_,_DBPASSWORD_,_DBNAME_);
$query1="SELECT d_title FROM domains WHERE domain_id='1'";
if (!($res1=@mysql_query($query1))) {trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);}
if (mysql_num_rows($res1)) {
    $domain_title=mysql_result($res,0,0);
}
print "domain_title is: $domain_title <br>";
```

So I'm trying -- WITH MYSQLI

```
$connection = db_connect_i(_DBHOSTNAME_,_DBUSERNAME_,_DBPASSWORD_,_DBNAME_);

$query="SELECT d_title FROM domains WHERE domain_id='1'";
if (!($res=@mysqli_query($connection,$query) {tigger_error(mysqli_error(),E_USER_ERROR);}
if (mysqli_num_rows($res)) {
    $aname=mysqli_result($res,0,0);
}

print "domain_title is: $domain_title <br>";
```

But the mysqli_result does not work as I know it
What is the best way to do this procedurally??

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to `mysql_result` in `mysqli`. In fact, that system of extracting database rows is extremely old.

Instead, `mysqli_query` returns a [result object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php). From there, you can use functions like `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

```
if (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))) {
    $aname = $row['d_title'];
}
```